# How to use if statements in classes

Tags: python, class, if-statement

I'm trying to make a simple library where the user can add and remove books from his shopping cart, but I don't know how to use if statements with OOP and classes.

```
try:
 class library:
     def __init__(self, books, customer):
         self.books = books
         self.customer = customer
    # sign:
     check = input("manager account(1), customer account(2): ")

     if check == "2":
    #age >= 18
         age = int(input("enter your age:  "))   
         if age >= 18:
            #name
             name = input("enter your firstname: ")

            # ID
             import random
             x = "ID"+str(random.randint(101,999))
             print(f"your ID is: {x}")
             print("you should memorize it")
             y = input("enter password that has at list 8 caracterse: ")

            # Password
             while len(y) < 8:
                 y = input("enter password that has at list 8 caracterse: ")
                 print(f"your password is: {y}")
             print("you should memorize it")
             data = [x,y]
             choice_1 = input("check your shopping cart(1): \nadd books to your shopping cart(2): \nremove books from your shopping cart(3): ")
             if choice_1 == "1":
                 def __str__(self):
                    return f"customer {self.customer} bought those books{self.books}"
             elif choice_1 == "2":
                 def __iadd__(self, other):
                     self.books.append(other)
                     return self

 order = library(["the golsen company"],"Mr.asad")
 print(order.books)
 order += input("enter a book: ")
 print(order.books)
except ValueError as ages:
    print(ages)
```

I don't know if this is the right way to use the `if` statement with classes so if you can just give me an example to show how it's done correctly?

Comment: Hello, it is function, not fonction. Thanks

Comment: it is just a typo, but thanks anyway XD

Comment: Okay, please fix your formatting in the class (I explained in my answer)

Comment: This is not a good design.  Your "library" class should hold books and maybe customers (not "costumer"), and have a way to add a remove things, but all of your user input and validation should be in your mainline code.  Or is it already that way, and it's just your cut-and-paste formatting that sucks?

Comment: `if` is not a function anyway. I changed the wording.

Answer (score 0):

when you said "fonction", I think you mean "function". When you make a `try:` block, you must also add an `except:` block. Also, don't put code directly in the class. Put it inside a function (a.k.a methods). I put the code starting from `# sign` in the `__int__` method. We generally don't put methods (functions) inside other methods. So, put the `__str__` and `__iadd__` methods outside the `__init__ method`. To call it, use `self.__str__()` and `self.__iadd__()`.

Here is the updated code:

```
try:
    class library:
        def __init__(self, books, customer):
            self.books = books
            self.customer = customer

            # sign:
            check = input("manager account(1), customer account(2): ")

            if check == "2":
                # age >= 18
                age = int(input("enter your age:  "))
                if age >= 18:
                    # name
                    name = input("enter your firstname: ")

                    # ID
                    import random
                    x = "ID" + str(random.randint(101, 999))
                    print(f"your ID is: {x}")
                    print("you should memorize it")
                    y = input("enter password that has at list 8 caracterse: ")

                    # Password
                    while len(y) < 8:
                        y = input("enter password that has at list 8 caracterse: ")
                        print(f"your password is: {y}")
                    print("you should memorize it")
                    data = [x, y]
                    choice_1 = input("check your shopping cart(1): \nadd books to your shopping cart(2): ")
                    if choice_1 == "1":
                        self.__str__()

                    elif choice_1 == "2":
                        self.__iadd__()

                # age < 18
                elif age < 18:
                    print("this library is not for your age")

        def __iadd__(self, other):
            self.books.append(other)
            return self

        def __str__(self):
            return f"customer {self.customer} bought those books{self.books}"
except:
    pass

order = library(["the golsen company"], "Mr.asad")
print(order.books)
order += input("enter a book: ")
print(order.books)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have rewritten your code to implement it in a more organized way.  Your class "library" was not really a library at all; it is a class for "orders", and I have renamed it as such. I didn't know what you wanted for the manager account, so the manager account just assigns a fake user name without requiring a signup.  I also fixed the spelling errors and the tabbing.

```
import random
import sys

class Order:
    def __init__(self, books, customer):
        self.books = books
        self.customer = customer
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.books.append(other)
        return self
    def __isub__(self, other):
        self.books.remove(other)
        return self
    def __str__(self):
        return f"customer {self.customer} bought those books {self.books}"

# sign in.

check = input("manager account(1),customer account(2): ")

if check == '1':
    x = 'manager'

if check == "2":
    #age >= 18

    age = int(input("enter your age:  "))   
    if age < 18:
        print("Sorry, you must be at least 18.")
        sys.exit(0)

    #name
    name = input("enter your firstname: ")

    # ID
    x = "ID"+str(random.randint(101,999))
    print(f"your ID is: {x}")
    print("you should memorize it")

    # Password
    y = input("enter password that has at least 8 characters: ")
    while len(y) < 8:
        y = input("enter password that has at least 8 characters: ")
    print(f"your password is: {y}")
    print("you should memorize it")

# Main menu.

order = Order( [], x )

while True:
    print('---')
    choice_1 = input("1. check your shopping cart\n2. add books to your shopping cart\n3. remove books from your shopping cart\n4. quit: ")
    if choice_1 == "1":
        print( order )
    elif choice_1 == "2":
        order += input("enter a book: ")
    elif choice_1 == "3":
        book = input("enter a book: ")
        if book in order.books:
            order -= book
        else:
            print( f"{book} is not in your cart." )
    elif choice_1 == "4":
        break
```